# Simple markup-based CMS

Tags: cms, framework, templating

I'm looking for CMS (or similar) to declare editable areas directly from template code, e.g. for quickly turning prototypes into editable websites.

I have something in mind like this:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <cms:editable type="richtext"><!-- generates a p tag with editable user content -->
  <cms:editable type="image"><!-- generates an img tag with editable user content -->
</html>
```

Of course, it would be great if it would integrate with other frameworks like Express/Jade in Node.js.

[MgnlKickstart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN8rI0QarQs) is the only close solution I've seen so far, but it's more of a shortcut to generate Magnolia components rather than a permanent solution, and I would like to maintain it directly in the form of a template to avoid as much configuration as I can.

Comment: Self-hosted (if yes, which server/technologies?) or hosted? Does license/price matter?

Comment: I think self-hosted would be better, but not with a specific technology; I'm just looking out what options there are. A licence should be affordable, i.e. not several thousands of dollars like for some enterprise systems. But it doesn't need to be free.