# Simple inline CMS to allow permission based editing of text blocks on custom website

Tags: html, cms, node.js

I'm designing a new site in HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript.  I need to allow non-technical individuals to do simple edits, basically just text and maybe WYSIWYG with images if possible.  They won't need to add new pages or restructure anything.

I've found [similar](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14792/which-tiny-open-source-cms-for-a-single-page-website/14811) [questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/cms-for-static-websites-that-allows-inline-editing-of-elements-with-specific-cla) but they're either for the wrong platform or have [slightly](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13923/simple-markup-based-cms) [different](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17809/looking-for-a-cms-with-editable-component-template-instances) requirements.

I need:

- Authentication
- Inline editing
- Simple
- Windows
- Node.js

Database doesn't really matter but I would prefer something simple.